# Forces in molecules (hydrogen molecular ion)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, atomic-physics

In Feynman's paper "Forces In Molecules" (https://www.dartmouth.edu/~phys71/p340_1.pdf) he makes the point that the forces derived from quantum mechanics (by differentiation of the Hamiltonian) are, in the context of molecules, just the classical Coulomb forces.

He goes on to say

"It now becomes clear why the strongest and most important attractive forces arise when there is a concentration of charge between two nuclei. The nuclei on each side of the concentrated charge are each strongly attracted to it. Thus they are, in effect, attracted toward each other. In an H2 molecule, for example, the anti-symmetrical wave function, because it must be exactly zero between the two H atoms, cannot concentrate charge between them. The symmetrical solution, however, can easily permit charge concentration between the nuclei, and hence it is only the solution which is symmetrical that leads to strong attraction, and the formation of a molecule, as is well known. It is clearly seen that concentrations of charge between atoms lead to strong attractive forces, and hence, are properly called valence bonds."

However, when I use the example of the hydrogen molecular ion, taking the symmetric wavefunction, squaring it for charge density and computing the force on one nucleus at the origin as

$$
F_z = \frac{e^2}{R^2} - e \int \frac{\rho}{r^2} \cos \theta \sin \theta r^2 d\theta \phi dr
$$

where the $\cos \theta$ is to project onto the z-axis, I find a purely repulsive force on the nucleus.

Why is this? Shouldn't it go to zero when $R = 2.5$ Bohr radii corresponding to the minimum on the binding energy curve (http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node129.html).

For completeness:

[image: Mathematica code used to compute the answer]